# ¿Mi aplicativo no genera un excel con EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, epplus

Buenos días quisiera saber porque mi aplicativo no genera el excel, agradezco de antemano por su ayuda

Mi controlador recibe una lista de datos desde el ajax que es cantidad de registros de mi tabla que esta en la vista, el problema es que debuggeo y si me trae data en el **array** y sigue todos los pasos pero no me genera el excel y no bota ningun error.

```
public ActionResult ExportarExcel(List<Sigeri> array)
        {

            var listado = array;

            var ruta =  new FileInfo("D:\\archivo_excel\\reporte_horas.xlsx");
            ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(ruta);
            //ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reportes");
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets["Gestion_horas"];

            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Comunicación";
            ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Com1";

            ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Reporte";
            ws.Cells["B2"].Value = "Seguimiento de Horas";

            ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "Fecha";
            ws.Cells["B3"].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy} at {0:H:  mm tt}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            ws.Cells["A6"].Value = "PROYECTO";
            ws.Cells["B6"].Value = "DESCRIPCION";
            ws.Cells["C6"].Value = "HORAS";
            ws.Cells["D6"].Value = "T. COBRADO";
            ws.Cells["E6"].Value = "COSTO BIENES";
            ws.Cells["F6"].Value = "MANO OBRA";
            ws.Cells["G6"].Value = "GASTOS GENERALES";
            ws.Cells["H6"].Value = "DEPRECIACION";

            int rowstart = 7;

            foreach (Sigeri obj in listado)
            {
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto; //obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto; //obj.Proyecto.IdProyecto;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Proyecto.Descripcion;//obj.Proyecto.Descripcion;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Horas;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.TotalCobrado;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.CostoBienes;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("F{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.ManoObra;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("G{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.GatosGenerales;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("H{0}", rowstart)].Value = obj.Depreciacion;
                rowstart++;

            }

             var myChart = ws.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.Line);


             //Define las series para el cuadro
             var series = myChart.Series.Add("C7: E7", "C6: E6");
             myChart.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
             myChart.Title.Text = "My Chart";
             myChart.SetSize(500, 400);

             //Agregar a la 6ta fila y a la 6ta columna
             myChart.SetPosition(6, 0, 10, 0);

             var myChart2 = myChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.ColumnClustered);
             //Define las series para el cuadro
             var series2 = myChart2.Series.Add("C7: E7", "C6: E6");

             //Agregar a la 6ta fila y a la 6ta columna
             //myChart2.SetPosition(6, 0, 10, 0);

            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            pkg.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = "Gestion_horas.xlsx" };

        }
```

Boton para hacer el exportar excel

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnExportar">Exportar Excel</button>
```

Código jquery que cuenta la cantidad de registros de la tabla y obtiene sus datos de cada uno de las filas y los guarda en un array que posteriormente lo pasa como parametro al ajax para enviarlo al controlador como una lista y ello lo almacena en una variable llamada listado.

```
$("#btnExportar").click(function () {
        var array = [];
        var filas = $("#contenido").find("tr");
        for (let i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
            var celdas = $(filas[i]).find("td");
            var obj = {
                Proyecto: {
                    IdProyecto: $(celdas[0]).text(),
                    Descripcion: $(celdas[1]).text()
                },
                Horas: $(celdas[2]).text(),
                TotalCobrado: $(celdas[3]).text(),
                CostoBienes: $(celdas[4]).text(),
                ManoObra: $(celdas[5]).text(),
                GatosGenerales: $(celdas[6]).text(),
                Depreciacion: $(celdas[7]).text()
            };
            array.push(obj);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: root + '/Sigeri/ExportarExcel',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(array),
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

En conclusión, deseo que me genere el excel porque mi debuggeo llega hasta el final pero no lo genera y no detecto porque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas usando Ajax:

Mandas un listado a tu controller y regresas un resultado al Ajax.

El resultado que estas regreando al ajax es de tipo FileStreamResult.

Cuando haces el return en tu controller, regresas al ajax, pero en tu ajax en el response no veo que estes abriendo o descargando o haciendo algo.

Si quieres descargarlo, tendrias que guardar ese stream de tu result en un tempdata o variable de sesion y luego mandar llamar un actionresult que regrese el archivo

Asi:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult Descargar()
{   
  var file= TempData["Archivo"];
  return File(file, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "MiArchivo.xlsx");
}
```

Espero te sirva

Aqui tu ajax regresa el archivo en la variable `data`, pero ahi no haces nada

```
success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
```

Sin embargo, el formato `FileStream()` que estas regresando del controller no hay manera de usarlo en javascript.

Por lo cual yo veo 2 opciones:
La 1a de guardar tu archivo en una variable de sesion
La 2a guardar tu archivo en el servidor, y luego obtener esa liga para descargar el archivo

Pero de las 2 maneras son 2 pasos:
1.- Ajax para convertir los datos al excel
2.- Descargar el archivo.

```
success: function (data) {
                    window.location="/Controller/Descargar";
                }
```

Espero haberme podido explicar

Comment: Estimado soy nuevo en ello me gustaría que fueras más especifico y gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: En resumen, tu resultado del controller nunca hace nada, porque llega al ajax, pero no hace nada.

Comment: el ajax solo lo uso para traer datos a mi controller y poder recorrer los datos y llenar mi excel y entiendo que no necesito devolver nada al ajax.

Comment: Edite mi repuesta, espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: En mi controlador ExportarExcel que deberia retornar

Comment: Podrias regresar algun indicador de que se genero y guardo el excel

Comment: Muchas gracias, Estimado ese era la solución.