# Descargar un archivo desde base de datos MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar, ya que tengo en mi BD archivos que almaceno en un varbinary.
No se si alguien sepa como convertir ese varbinary de nuevo al archivo original y poderlo descargar al convertirlo al archivo original.

Edito:
El poco código que llevo en esto es el siguiente:

```
public ActionResult DescargarDocumento(int id)
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;
        string nombre = "";
        string cont = "";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Archivo,Nombre,ContentType FROM INV_ENC  WHERE IDaplicativo = @ID", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (dr.Read())
            {
                fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
                nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                cont = dr.GetString(2);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Ajax por el que mando a llamar el action para descargar el documento.

```
function DescargarDocumento(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'DescargarDocumento',
    data: {id},
    success: function () {
    }
})
```

}

Comment: Israel, tendras que dar mas detalles. Que utilizas para consultar la base de datos? Entity Framework? Dapper?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverfloeES!! Para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar se **recomienda** aportar el código que tengas hasta el momento o lo que has intentado para poder tener un punto de partida. Un saludo :)

Comment: Si, no me equivoco ya que soy algo nuevo en todo esto, ADO.NET, traigo mi informacion del archivo como los bytes, el content type y su nombre de la base de datos ya con esto busco convertirlo al archivo original, no se si esto ayude mas, igual la peticion de descarga la hago por medio de JS con Ajax, mando por medio de un POST el ID del archivo a descargar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que tienes el Byte array `byte[]` puedes regresar el archivo con su nombre, necesitas un Action de tipo FileResult

```
public FileResult Descargar()
{    

   //Tu codigo que ya tienes

  byte[] fileData = null;
    string nombre = "";
    string cont = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Archivo,Nombre,ContentType FROM INV_ENC  WHERE IDaplicativo = @ID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (dr.Read())
        {
            fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
            nombre = dr.GetString(1);
            cont = dr.GetString(2);
        }
        con.Close();
    }



    return File(fileData, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, nombre);
}
```

Comment: El nombre debe de llevar la extension del archivo

Comment: Habia intentado ya de esa forma, con response y no logro que se efectué la descarga del archivo, no se si yo este haciendo algo mal. De hecho lo que me ayuda a descargar es especificándole una ruta en donde guarde el documento, pero me gustaría mas que el usuario eliga la carpeta de destino y pueda ver el progreso de su descarga

Comment: Como estas llamando ese Action? En algun boton? Por medio de ajax o como? Edita tu codigo porfavor

Comment: Estoy llamando el action por medio de un Ajax, por ahi le envio el ID del archivo que va a buscar en la BD.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286744/mi-aplicativo-no-genera-un-excel-con-epplus/286753

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo leí y comprendí perfectamente lo que estaba sucediendo, lo adapte a lo que hago y ya me descarga el archivo, Muchísimas gracias!!